# Why ENV behave like a hash, but it's an Object class

Tags: ruby

Am I right to consider ENV a Hash

```
ENV['HOME']

=>'/Users/yozloy'
```

But

```
ENV.class

#=>Object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It implements most of the Hash methods but apparently a few are missing:

```
[:default, :default=, :default_proc, :default_proc=, :merge!, :merge, :flatten, :compare_by_identity, :compare_by_identity?]
```

Most of these you'd never think to use, but `merge` and `flatten` could be useful.

Remember that `ENV` isn't exactly a Hash, but a wrapper around the environment variables and the associated methods for retrieving and setting them.

Answer (score 4):

CRuby sources tell you in hash.c

```
envtbl = rb_obj_alloc(rb_cObject);
rb_extend_object(envtbl, rb_mEnumerable);
...
/*
 * ENV is a Hash-like accessor for environment variables.
 *
 * See ENV (the class) for more details.
 */
rb_define_global_const("ENV", envtbl);
```

So although it is a plain object, `envtbl` can be treated like a Hash, although some methods are missing as stated by tadman.

Comment: thanks for point out the source code of CRuby, but BTW what's CRuby exactly? I can't get decent result after googling.

Comment: Oh, it's the "main" Ruby version, sometimes also called MRI, the one you can download at [ruby-lang.org](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/).